# ThreeJS and Typescript: How to trace or outline the path an object is rotating on?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-three-fiber

I've been working on a model of the Solar System for a bit now. I've managed to render all of the planets in the Solar System(sorry Pluto) and have them orbit about the Sun.

I've realized that it might be helpful to show the orbits of the planets along a colored path. But I have no idea how to do this.

Any ideas?
The file I will showcase is the Earth file, which is rendered in another file i've named Skysphere.

Skysphere:

```
import { Canvas, useThree } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { PerspectiveCamera, PointerLockControls, OrbitControls, Stars } from "@react-three/drei";
import Sun from "../PlanetsModels/Sun";
import Earth from "../PlanetsModels/Earth";
import Mars from "../PlanetsModels/Mars"
import Mercury from "../PlanetsModels/Mercury";
import Venus from "../PlanetsModels/Venus"
import Jupiter from "../PlanetsModels/Jupiter"
import Saturn from "../PlanetsModels/Saturn"
import Uranus from "../PlanetsModels/Uranus"
import Neptune from "../PlanetsModels/Neptune"
import { SignatureKind } from "typescript";
  


export default function System() {
    return(
    <Canvas style={{backgroundColor: 'Black', width:window.innerWidth, height:window.innerHeight}}>
        <ambientLight intensity = {1}/>            
        <Stars radius = {300} depth = {60} count = {10000} factor = {8} saturation = {0}/>
        <Suspense fallback = {null}>
            <Sun/>
            <Mercury/>
            <Venus/>
            <Mars/>
            <Earth/>
            <Jupiter/>
            <Saturn/>
            <Uranus/>
            <Neptune/>
        </Suspense> 
        <OrbitControls
        enablePan={ true}
        enableZoom={true}
        enableRotate={true}
      />
    </Canvas>
    );
};
```

My Earth file is below:

```
Auto-generated by: https://github.com/pmndrs/gltfjsx
*/

import * as THREE from 'three'
import React, { useRef } from 'react'
import {useFrame} from '@react-three/fiber'
import { useGLTF } from '@react-three/drei'
import { GLTF } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader'

type GLTFResult = GLTF & {
  nodes: {
    Cube001: THREE.Mesh
  }
  materials: {
    ['Default OBJ']: THREE.MeshStandardMaterial
  }
}

export default function Model(props: JSX.IntrinsicElements['group']) {
  const group = useRef<THREE.Group>()
  const { nodes, materials } = useGLTF('/Earth.glb') as GLTFResult
  useFrame(() => { //rotates sun around its axis
    group!.current!.rotation.y += .0037;
   })
  return (
    <group ref={group} {...props} dispose={null}>
      <mesh geometry={nodes.Cube001.geometry} material={materials['Default OBJ']} visible = {true} position = {[18.46,0,0]} scale = {.00297} />
    </group>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I can think of is to create a [TorusGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=torus#api/en/geometries/TorusGeometry) with a small `tube` value and a `radius` matching the planet's distance from the sun. If you add a `MeshBasicMaterial` to that mesh, it'll look like a solid line and be unaffected by lighting.

[image: Screenshot of the ThreeJS Torus constructor with a small tube value, creating a very thin ring.]